# Sentence construction with "as ... so"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, construction

For example, if someone was driving in front of you in a car breaking the rules and continues to do so, then how do you say using a construction?

Is this correct to use this one? Or maybe there is another construction?

> ***As*** he drove ***so*** he is driving all the way.

and also

> ***As*** she went to McDonald's, ***so*** she always goes there.

Any sentences without changing the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. I actually don't know what you intend by it (which is an indication that it is not idiomatic in English).

This use of *as ... so ...* (which is rather literary) is for drawing a parallel between two different things.

Without the *so*, it is a normal English construction, with a sense of "since" or "because":

> As she went to McDonald's once, she always goes there.

implies that because she went there first (and presumably liked it) she always goes there.

But you seem to be trying to use it in a different way, to suggest a parallel. This does exist, but as I say it is rather literary, and it is used of two different things. So you might say:

> As she went to McDonalds, so she goes to Burger King

(though you would probably be playing with language if you did, because the literary construction does not match the mundane content).

But it doesn't sound right comparing part and the whole of the same thing in the way you are trying to use it.

Comment: I hope something exists for that and you can help me. I am looking for it, and I cannot find it.

Comment: Right, I get it. You don't want the _as_. _She went to McDonalds once, so she still goes there._ - but the _so_ has the sense of _therefore_, which you might not  want. For the driving one, it would be much more natural to turn it round: _He's still driving the way he did before_.

Comment: What about this?: "The way he drove is the way he is driving" or "The way he is driving is the way he drove"

Comment: It's grammatical, but it's almost meaningless without something to define the two parts (like _before_ that I used). I guess that with suitable context it might just be meaningful.